Black screen after login and shutdown (I have tried several solutions): Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS & Nvidia
Hi! I'm new to AskUbuntu, and I really need help! I've tried (for several weeks now) to switch from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, but the OS just does not function properly. I've tried several proposed solutions, and they didn't work. Since I'm not an expert at Linux, I feel a bit desperate. If someone could help me with this issue, I would be truly grateful.
1. Summary of the problem:
I suffer from two problems that has been described earlier here, here and here. The problems can be described in the following way:

Black screen after login (the OS does not log in)
Black screen after shutdown (the OS does not power down)

When I power on the computer, I reach the login prompt and enter the password, but when I press enter, the screen (usually) freezes at a blank screen. Similarly, when I power off the computer, the screen (usually) freezes at a blank screen, and I have to force the shutdown with the power button. These issues were present when I tried Ubuntu, Pop OS and Mint.
2. Hardware details:

Processor:    Intel Core i5-12400F
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050
Memory: Corsair Vengeance LPX Black 32GB (2x16GB), 3200MHz, CL16, DDR4 SDRAM
Storage: WD Blue SN570 NVMe SSD, 1TB, M.2
Motherboard:  ASUS PRIME B660M-A WIFI D4 (DDR4)
Cooling:  Cooler Master Hyper 212 ARGB Black Edition
Power Supply: Corsair / Cooler Master 550W, 80+ Gold
Case: Fractal Design Meshify 2 Compact, TG Dark Tint

3. What I have tried:

I have reinstalled Ubuntu from a separate flashdrive and separate ISO.
I have updated the kernel.
I have tried previous kernels.
I have tried several Nvidia drivers (including, of course, the recommended one, e.g. 550).
I have activated "nomodeset" as specified here: https://www.linux.org/threads/black-screen-after-grub-if-nomodeset-is-not-set.47935/
I have followed the solution from System76: https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/


Have you checked that the firmware on your motherboard is the latest?  "nomodeset" only is needed before you install any Nvidia drivers.  Maybe leftover Nvidia configs are interfering with each other -- purge (not just remove) every package with "nvidia" in the name, then try the 550 or later from ubuntu-drivers install. Single monitor? If using Wayland, try xorg at the login password prompt click on the gear icon to select. Have you tried a 24.10 ubuntu with the 6.11 kernel?
